# How to create with belongsTo association in Sequelize

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I am trying to create with association in sequelize but I am getting an error saying `userId` cannot be null.

I am using sequelize version `^6.31.1`

I have following models

`User.js`

```
User.init({
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.UUID,
      defaultValue: uuid.v4(),
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true,
    },
    firstName: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    lastName: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
    },
    balance: DataTypes.DECIMAL(10, 2),
   }, {
    sequelize,
    tableName: 'users',
    underscored: true,
    paranoid: true,
  });
```

`Account.js`

```
Account.init({
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.UUID,
      defaultValue: uuid.v4(),
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true,
    },
    name: DataTypes.STRING,
    bankId: {
      type: DataTypes.UUID,
      allowNull: false,
      references: {
        model: "banks",
        key: 'id'
      },
      onUpdate: "RESTRICT",
      onDelete: "RESTRICT",
    },
    userId: {
      type: DataTypes.UUID,
      allowNull: false,
      references: {
        model: "users",
        key: 'id'
      },
      onUpdate: "RESTRICT",
      onDelete: "RESTRICT",
    },
    balance: DataTypes.DOUBLE
  }, {
    sequelize,
    underscored: true,
    paranoid: true,
    modelName: 'Account',
    tableName: 'accounts',
  });
```

**Association**

```
Account.belongsTo(User, { foreignKey: 'userId' })
User.hasMany(Account, { foreignKey: "userId" })
```

I am trying to add a record to table as follow:

```
await Account.create({
  name: "tom-account-01",
  bankId: "e20036e5-74a9-4aab-8997-b33058b475a1",
  balance: 100,
  user: {
    firstName: 'john',
    lastName: "doe",
    balance: 20000,
  }
}, {
  include: [User]
})
```

This throws an error saying `ValidationError [SequelizeValidationError]: notNull Violation: Account.userId cannot be null`

I could not find good example in the sequelize documentation on how to create using belongsTo association.

Thank you...

Answer (score 0):

Everything is in error message `Account.userId cannot be null`. If User does not exist, you have to create it and provide userId for account record.

```
const user = await User.create({
     firstName: 'john',
     lastName: "doe",
     balance: 20000,
})

await Account.create({
  name: "tom-account-01",
  bankId: "e20036e5-74a9-4aab-8997-b33058b475a1",
  balance: 100,
  userId: user.id
 })
```

Also you should use [transaction](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/other-topics/transactions/) for this.

Comment: Does sequelize provide methods wherein in can I do that in single command. They have provided documentation for hasMany [in documentation](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/advanced-association-concepts/creating-with-associations/). Looking something similar for adding belongsTo association